# Trying to get last element from a unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've spent an unhealthy amount of time trying to figure this out and think I'm just having some kind of brain-fart. This is the code i have so far:

```
alert($('#messages2 ul li').index()); // Need to add something in index
```

Basically this application uses Node.js to send and receive messages (A chat application). Whenever a message is sent, it is `appended` to the `UL` (Their are no special ID tags for the `LI tags`). This is the code I'm using to `append` (Which works just fine!)

```
$('#messages2').append('<li>'+ "[ <strong>" + socket1+"</strong> ] "+msg + '</li>');
```

What I want to do is get the last item in the `UL`, I'm sure this is not too difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [last](http://api.jquery.com/last/) in jQuery:

```
$('ul li').last(). /* do something with it */
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it directly with a jQuery selector:

```
$("#messages2 ul li:last-child")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use different ways

```
- $('ul li').last()
- $("ul li:last")
- $("ul li:last-child")
- $("ul li")[$("ul li").length-1] // if($("ul li").length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3's new last-child property. Now you don't have to create a custom class and find a way to append it additionally to an ID or another class.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the li:last-child selector

Here is html...

- foo
- second child
- bar

Here is the CSS

ul li:last-child{

```
background: red;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/q6ymgvfp/